# Jenkins Remote Trigger Url giving blank page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have configured remote trigger url with token for all the projects using my jenkins instance to trigger the Jobs.

```
http://jenkins_url/view/Test/job/Test/build?token=test
```

On clicking the url, a blank screen shows up. I have given view permission to anonymous user. Is there a way I can display a success/failure message on clicking the url. Project teams find the blank page annoying. Please help.

I searched for other similar questions on SO, but could not find anything worth trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote trigger url isn't mean for humans to use - it's there for automation. If you need a link for your end-users to click - simply give them the regular 
`http://jenkins_url/view/Test/job/Test/build?delay=0sec` and grant everyone build permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @antweiss. Is there a better way to do this without making the teams access the jenkins url?

Comment: I don't really see what's wrong with users accessing Jenkins, but if you relally want to obscure it  - you can write a web page with java script performing the REST call to the remote trigger url or wrap the call in a script (using jenkins-cli or simply curl)